# Javascript alerts and using php variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have the below section of code where I want to display how many orders have been added if conditions of the $orderstat are met. The alert works but not with the $orderstat variable inside it. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
    session_start();
$orderstat = $_SESSION['orderstat']; 
if ( $orderstat == "1" || $orderstat == "2" || $orderstat == "3" || $orderstat == "4") {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
**echo 'alert('<?php echo $orderstat; ?>' + "order/s successfully added to Job")';**
echo '</script>';
}
session_destroy();
```

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP string syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, then take a VERY close look at your echo/alert line.

Comment: Though in this case the problem isn't the PHP, it's the javascript. However, this is EASILY diagnosed yourself if you use a simple debugger. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line 
`echo 'alert('<?php echo $orderstat; ?>' + "order/s successfully added to Job")';`

to

`echo 'alert("'.$orderstat.' order/s successfully added to Job")';`

You are nesting the php again and again in line echo 'alert('' + "order/s successfully added to Job")';

Answer (score -1):

```
    session_start();
    $orderstat = $_SESSION['orderstat']; 
    if ( $orderstat == "1" || $orderstat == "2" || $orderstat == "3" || $orderstat == "4") {
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("<?php echo $orderstat; ?> order/s successfully added to Job");
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    session_destroy();
```

Here, I have made correction. Instead of echo we can right code in this way. This is working code. Please check.

Comment: don't just repaste the (fixed) code without explaining WHAT you changed.

Comment: @MarcB Indeed this is why I down voted. Code only answers are NG.

Comment: You can check now. This is working code. It will alert as "1 order/s successfully added to Job" (for $orderstat = 1).